# Design assistance: Calculation of time with expression parsed at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, database-design, expression-evaluation

I have some columns in the database which contain time in`HH:MM` format. Now if there are simple expressions like `11:00 - 12:00` then i can easily make an extension method in C# called as `SubtractTime` and pass my arguments at runtime. I will store my formula in the database for example:

```
Condition                     Value
ExamTimeRemaing > 10:00       SubtractTime(Original,Remaining)
```

Now in the above case i can call my `SubtractTime` function using reflection at runtime, however my problem is this, what if my expressions become complicated like:

```
10:00 + 12:00 * 00:02 - 10:11
```

How do i parse such expressions? I do not require help in coding as i already have my extensions for converting time to ticks then to `HH:MM`. This is more of a design question. I want a scalable solution so that i can efficiently create a Rule Engine.

Comment: What on earth is the result of 12:00 * 00:02 ?

Comment: This is a typical lexer/parser question. I can highly recommend reading up on what lexers and grammers are. Antlr and gold parser are good starting points.

Comment: The multiplication of HH MM's needs to be elaborated as @PaulZahra mentioned, where is a practical application of this?

Comment: +1 to Stefan's recommendation.  You're talking about creating your own DSL, I recommend Antlr myself for creating your own grammar around what you're looking for.  More work, but it will be the most stable and flexible.

Answer (score 0):

I would say store it as a string and find the operators. Make a recursive function ParseAndCalc(string input) which parses and calculates the results in the right order. Something like this:

```
double ParseAndCalc(string input)
{
    string[] sub;
    double result = 0;
    if(input.Contains("+"))
    {
        sub = input.Split('+');
        foreach(string substring in sub)
        {
            result += ParseAndCalc(substring);
        }
    }
    else if (input.Contains("-"))
    {
        sub = input.Split('-');
        foreach(string substring in sub)
        {
            result -= ParseAndCalc(substring);
        }
    }
    else if (input.Contains("*"))
    {
        sub = input.Split('*');
        foreach(string substring in sub)
        {
            result *= ParseAndCalc(substring);
        }
    }
    else if (input.Contains("/"))
    {
        sub = input.Split('/');
        foreach(string substring in sub)
        {
            double parsed = ParseAndCalc(substring);
            if(parsed != 0)
            {
                result /= ParseAndCalc(substring);
            }
            else
            {
                // Error
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I might have misread but it seems you are saying the order of operator precedence is additions and subtractions **before** multiplication? It should go 12:00 * 00:02 and then left (+) to right (-). For example, using brackets to illustrate the correct order: `10 + (12 * (2 / 60)) - 10.1833333`

Comment: You're right, I'll correct it. I was not really paying attention to the actual calculation as multiplying time by time is strange anyway. The concept is good though.

Comment: Hmmmm I personally wouldn't say its a good concept, unless its a Time Machine or hack to make my work hours look longer :) I've never heard of multiplying hours by minutes, I asked the OP to elaborate. **Edit:** if you mean good concept as in a calculator, DataTables have a `Compute` method. eg `var eleven = new DataTable().Compute(2 + 3 * 3);`

Comment: I meant the concept of using a recursive function. I'm not sure what multiplying time is supposed to mean. I assume it's meant to be 2 instead of 00:02, and the OP wasn't paying attention to the details of the example.

Comment: It's bizare to say the least, you could equally assume that 00:02 means 2 minutes * 12:00 which could be 12 * 60 minutes = 720, therefore 720 x 2.... making 12 in the afternoon 12:00 be 12 midnight (24:00) assumptions are often deadly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to consider development and maintenance overhead. Creating expression parser is absolutely ridiculous by using Antlr etc, I would instead use a ready made solution like JavaScript Engine like Jurassic or any other .NET based simple JavaScript engine.

**SQL Stored Procedures/User Defined Functions**

Also, if your rules are stored within the database itself, then instead of making parser, you could use capabilities of SQL itself to parse and evaluate expression. You can dynamically compose SQL expression and pass parameters. Or create stored procedure or User defined function those are well tested, well known and scalable and stays within the context of database.

**Open Source .NET JavaScript Engines**

You can still store your formula in database in JavaScript format, first JavaScript is well known, well understood and is capable of handling complex expressions. There are many free and stable JavaScript engine which offers rich language features as well as you can still use existing JavaScript libraries within your formula. For example in future you need Base64, you can simply get Base64 from some github and put it in your JavaScript.

**C# Compiler**

CSharpCompilerProvider class offers you a way to compile C# source into an assembly, what I would do is create a source file by using some text template, compile and store assembly in the SQL along with formulat and when I need to invoke expression, I can fetch compiled version, load it with `Assembly.Load` and create parsed class which has some interface and invoke it's method. .NET will compile and will give you assembly, which you can store in database as `varbinary(max)`.

Answer (score 0):

The answers here tell you how to do this well enough. If you decide to attempt this, I'd probably choose the ANTLR route myself.

That said, I would seriously think about WHY you want to do this. You mentioned you were building a "rules engine". From this, I'm assuming that you've got a database or something where you want to store a bunch of business logic as "rules" and then have the "rules engine" read this an apply it to some data. As part of this, you want some sort of expression parser to be able to parse and evaluate certain kinds of rules.

In looking at a design like this, I would be careful to not mix up the problems of parsing the rules and executing them. You can likely encode the rules in XML, JSON, or whatever your favorite content format is. If you do that, you don't have to write a parser at all. You just evaluate the expressions.

```
var myRule = [
  { $value: '10:00' },
  { $add: '12:00' },
  { $multiply: 2 },
  { $subtract: '10:11' }
]
```